# How to Make a Mirror that Bounces / Reflects Spot Light as a Projector Would?

Tags: mirror, reflection

Playing around and enjoying this method to simulate an image projection as a video projector would in Blender. Using [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/adahnQCqmw0).

I am now trying to see how it might be possible to simulate "bouncing" this image off of a mirror type surface or material in Blender?

The idea being it would act as a real life projector beam bouncing off of a mirror would such that the reflected image is still in focus.

So far I have only been able to get the image to be a very diffuse reflection. See screen shot.

Is this simply a setting in the material portion of the mirror or is it deeper than that?

Thank you for any tips!

[image: mirror reflection in Blender]

Comment: Is this perhaps a limitation of Cycles as per this Reddit post?

"Turns out its a cycles limitation, something about tracing rays backwards from the camera instead of from the light source."

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/del389/light_not_bouncing_realistically_off_mirror/

Comment: Without looking at the blend file, my immediate thought is that if the surface of the “mirror” is smooth, this should work right off the bat. Otherwise, you may have to do some trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Light reflected with a mirror is called caustics in CG. Cycles is sadly not capable to render reflective caustics well even with recent improvements in caustics rendering. You could look into other render engines like LuxCoreRender.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up I will definitely look into that render engine you mentioned. Thank you!